# Can I submit an iOS app which only gets the device IDFA and open third party app programmatically?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

Will this kind of App get approved?
I only need this app in order for my mobile website to be able to instruct this app to open another third party app(if installed on the device).

Comment: Questions regarding app approval are off topic, however it seems unlikely that this app would be approved.  Refer to section 4.2 - https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality Why doesn't your web site just launch the third party app directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chances of application rejection is pretty much high if your application only opens a web page or third party app. In that case apple developers will you to refer to your website or construct a webpage to solve your purpose.